# python list TypeError 'slice' object is not iterable, create new list then sum new sliced list

Tags: python, list

I am very new to programming and python so please be patient.

I have the following code:

```
Date_Entered = str(raw_input('Enter Current Date in the form mm/dd/yyyy: '))
Split_Date_Entered = Date_Entered.split('/')
Base_Year = 2013
Base_Month = 1
Base_Day = 1
Entered_Year = int(Split_Date_Entered[2])
Entered_Month = int(Split_Date_Entered[0])
Entered_Day = int(Split_Date_Entered[1])
NumberOfDaysInMonth = [0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
N = NumberOfDaysInMonth
Month_Difference = Entered_Month - Base_Month
MD = Month_Difference
```

My goal is to take a date in the same year (2013) and calculate the days elapse since that day. 
I would like the Month_Differnce to serve as my index to the NumbersOfDaysInMonth list. 
Then I want to summate the items from NumbersOfDaysInMonth from the first item to whatever the Month_Difference turns out to be
I have tried slicing list and them summing the resulting list and summating it by:

```
slice(N[0],N[MD])
```

with an output of

```
slice(0, 31, None)
```

I was a bit confused by why it was returning the right most value of 'None' but I proceed to try to summate the values by,
I assigned the list to the variable NewList and then tried to sum the list by:

```
sum(NewList)
```

I get the error message of

**TypeError: 'slice' object is not iterable**

Can some one help me understand the concept of the error
And show me how to correct it

Comment: A suggestion for writing Python code: only classes should have capitalized names. It's very difficult to read your code because none of the names look more significant than any other.

Comment: can you please show the NewList items?

Answer (score 1):

maybe [this article](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/) help you.

```
sum(NewList[slice(start,stop)])
sum(NewList[slice(1,10)])
```